# Convert a mssql openjson array type value result to a table?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

I have a json object in my Microsoft (MS) SQL Server query. This JSON object does have one value, which is an array of strings.

```
--this variable holds my JSON object with a value of array type. 
declare @json nvarchar(max) = N'{
                    "value": [
                        "tapiwanashe",
                        "robert",
                        "emmerson",
                        "ruwimbo",
                        "takudzwa",
                        "munyaradzi"
                    ]
                }'
```

My goal is to write a SQL query using the supported MS SQL Server JSON functions that produces a table with one column and six rows of the values in the JSON object value array above.

I have tried to run the JSON_QUERY and the OPENJSON functions. However, both of the two functions return an array of strings as the output. I would like to have a result with one column and six rows.

```
select JSON_QUERY(@json, '$.value')
```

```
select [value] from OPENJSON(@json)
```

The result I am getting is:

```
value
---------------
[
   "tapiwanashe",
   "robert",
   "emmerson",
   "ruwimbo",
   "takudzwa",
   "munyaradzi"
]
```

However, the result I am expecting to get looks like this:

```
value
-----------
tapiwanashe
robert
emmerson
ruwimbo
takudzwa
munyaradzi
```

The result must preserve the order on which the values appear in the value array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
declare @json nvarchar(max) = N'{
                    "value": [
                        "tapiwanashe",
                        "robert",
                        "emmerson",
                        "ruwimbo",
                        "takudzwa",
                        "munyaradzi"
                    ]
                }'

select value 
from openjson(@json,'$.value')
order by [key]
```

outputs

```
value
----------
tapiwanashe
robert
emmerson
ruwimbo
takudzwa
munyaradzi
```

Comment: Thank you. This answered my question. I will go ahead and accept this as an answer to my question.

Comment: `SELECT [value] from OPENJSON(@json, '$.value')
ORDER BY value`

Comment: @HasanMahmood, thank you for your comment. However, I would like to reserve the order on which the values appear in the array value.

Comment: @HakunaN then you must `order by [key]` otherwise, as with all SELECT statements the order that the rows are returned is undefined and subject to change.